# Regression to estimate parameters

Tags: regression, least-squares, total-least-squares

I would like some suggestions to tackle the following problem.

Given a system

$y = X\beta$

where $y \in \mathcal{R}^m$, $X \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times n}$, $m\geq n$, and $\beta \in \mathcal{R}^n$,

I want to estimate $\beta$.

However, I have perturbations in both $y$ and $X$, i.e. I am given

$y+\delta y = (X+\delta X)\hat{\beta}$.

What is the right way to estimate $\hat{\beta}$ such that the latter is as close as possible to $\beta$?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, I will assume:

1. We are dealing with a simple linear regression with one $X$ variable
2. The error in $Y$ and $X$ are normally distributed

---

In a standard linear regression, we aim to model $Y = \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon$.

What are the random variables? They are $Y \sim N(\alpha + \beta x, \sigma_y^2)$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma_y^2)$

In your model, we have $Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$, where $x \mapsto X = x+\eta$, where $\eta \sim N(0, \sigma_x^2)$.

From this, $Y = \alpha + \beta x + \beta \eta + \epsilon$. The errors can be combined such that $Y \sim N(\alpha + \beta x, \beta^2 \sigma_x^2+ \sigma_y^2)$.

This gives rise to 2 cases:

1. If $\sigma_x^2 \approx 0$ then we can model using a regular regression
2. If $\sigma_x^2 >> 0$, then you will need to go back to deriving a maximum likelihood estimator for $\hat{\beta}$